# Ayuda Api Facebook para bot php

Tags: php, api, facebook

un gran saludos a todos, soy de poco preguntar, ya que me gusta mucho indagar en google primero. pero esta vez ya no encuentro nada que me pueda resolver o encaminar.

Estoy desarrollando un bot para facebook en php muy simple, lo que necesito es que la persona que envié un mensaje, algo parecido a esto: "Atención SRES, necesito ayuda con mi TDC, mi cédula es.....", el mismo leerlo, tomar ese mensaje y crear un ticket, y que le responda al usuario algo como: "Gracias por escribir fulano de tal...."

Ya cree mi app en developers.facebook.com genere mi access_token y mi verify_token, configure el Webhooks y marque las casillas correspondientes, y también suscribí la pagina que recibirán los mensajes y el bot responderá. igualmente lo que dice de revisión para app de messenger, es decir todo lo que me da para configurar en google en cuanto tutorial eh visto.

incluso eh tomado varios codigos de github y visto varios vídeos de youtube y ninguno al enviar el mensaje me responde, y el webhooks me acepta la url de respuesta, digamos que todo como deber ser.

Uno de los últimos códigos use fue este:

```
if (isset($_GET['hub_verify_token'])) { 
    if ($_GET['hub_verify_token'] === 'xxxxx') {
        echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
        return;
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Verify Token';
        return;
    }
}

/* receive and send messages */
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (isset($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'])) {

    $sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id']; //sender facebook id
    $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']; //text that user sent

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=xxxxxx';

    /*initialize curl*/
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    /*prepare response*/
    $jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
        "id":"' . $sender . '"
        },
        "message":{
            "text":"You said, ' . $message . '"
        }
    }';
    /* curl setting to send a json post data */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    if (!empty($message)) {
        $result = curl_exec($ch); // user will get the message
    }
}
```

Me gustaría es una asesoría si hay otra opción de la api de facebok, si este tipo de código ya no funciona, ya que es el mas que eh visto en la web.

Eh usado otras apis como la de twitter (incluso logre leer normal los DM los teet responderlos e interactuar con el usuario como de si un humano le respondiera.), Instagram un poco eh logrado enviar msj de promociones, peero con la de facebook llevo dos días y no me responde ningún mensaje.

Por favor le agradecería mucho la ayuda, no eh hecho muchas preguntas en este foro, si algo esta mal por favor me lo indican...

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola asegurate que en la parte de webhooks del Bot tengas habilitado estos => messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins, message_deliveries. 
Aunque nunca lo he intentado con PHP + FB Messenger, yo haría algo como esto =>

```
$sender = "<PSI>";
// Por si en el string se nos paso algo mal, es mas facil pasearlo desde un array y generar el json de envío
$jsonData = json_encode(["recipient" => ["id" => $sender], "message" => ["text" => "You said $message"]]);

$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Deberia de funcionar
```

En nuestro caso usamos algo que se llama Bot Framework (https://dev.botframework.com)  es mas facil de configurar y ademas ofrece el Bot Emulator que te permite hacer las pruebas en local antes de enviar al bot a produccion :)

Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias Ya voy probar.

Comment: Amigo, sigo en las mismas, no eh podido solucionar, lo que me dices ya lo revise y probé, note que en la sección de errores me da error 403, obviamente es de permisos, pero como comente la url fue aceptada es decir la api verifico con el hub_verify_token, y en el hosting tiene los permisos normales yo puedo acceder a la url donde tengo el archivo que tiene el código. Espero alguien puede seguir iluminándome.! muchas  gracias!